# Using an alias to get further into directory

Tags: unix, terminal, directory, path, alias

I created a alias to the directory `data`,
now I want to be able to access subdirectories for a script in the same manner as a normal directory, for example `data/sub1`.

The alias on its own works in the terminal but I can't access the path it stands for ( `/User/usr/Folder/Subfolder/data` ) in the command line arguments of the script.
`python skript.py -input data/path/ -output data/path`.

I tried `$data`, `{data}` and different quotation marks around the path but wasn't able to access it.

I saw that at some similar questions link `-ln` was suggested but it sounds like this is similar to an environment variable, the later didn't work for me reliably therefor I haven't tried the link yet.

Any suggestions, again I would prefer the alias but I'm open for anything else.

Kind regards

Comment: For the moment, I use ".zshrc" to call ```export DATA="/User/usr/Folder/Subfolder/data"``` while this is - in my opinion far from Ideal it makes it usable.

If one of you has a solution to use an alias I would welcome it.

Comment: A symbolic link, alias of function (what is better then an alias) are all overkill. Just get `python skript.py -input "${data}/path/" -output "${data}/path"` working. Perhaps the path has a space (that is why I am using double quotes). First try `echo "${data}"` and replace echo by `ls` when it works.